# Can I embed multiple copies of the Python interpreter in a multi-threaded program?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a multi-threaded program. I want to embed a python interpreter. I don't want to use Python's threading; I want to have multiple copies of the Python interpreter running.

- Can I do this? (That is, does Python have global variables, or is everything done with a single Python interpreter object?)
- Is there an example of a program that does this?
- If I can't do it, my plan is to have multiple Python interpreters, each running in their own address space, and try to do something with inter-process communication. But that seems really hard.
- Or is Python multi-threaded well enough now that I can embed it multi-threaded?

Thanks.

Comment: Python interprocess communication, at least for passing in standard input and capturing standard output, is actually quite easy.  http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Multiple processes and inter-process communication will probably be less hard than dealing with threading. Just saying.

Comment: What is the question in the fourth point? FUD?

Comment: Last fourth point is that Python has a multithreading primitive, but it may use a global lock. I don't know if it's multithreading well enough to respond to C-function calls in a multithreaded manner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's interpreter uses global state, and as such you can only have one interpreter per process. You can try using `multiprocessing` to run multiple processes, each with their own interpreter, but I'm not sure how well that would play with embedding.

Comment: Thanks. That's unfortunate. I'll need to write an embedding shim that transfers the data to another process, or that implements some kind of global lock.